# Is it advised to study alone without a havruta?

Tags: torah-study, yeshiva-school

Is it advised to study alone without a havruta ? Is it also advised to study at home instead that at a yeshiva if the only available yeshiva is not of our hashkafa ?

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be allowed to learn without a havruta? ....Also, what are you learning?

Comment: @Shokhet ,maybe he is referring to Makkos 10 Rebbi Yossi bReb Chanina...

Comment: @Sam: what this passage is about ? I changed my question: I meant "advised", not "allowed". Sorry

Comment: Is your chavrusa going to be of that "other" hashkafa or you'll be bringing your own chavrusa but the institution will be not of your hashkafa?

Comment: try with a suitable chavrusa and without. decide which is better for you. most people find a chavrusa helps enormously

Comment: I meant like YEZ

Answer (score 4):

Masheches Makos 10a brings this idea

מאי דכתיב חרב אל הבדים ונואלו חרב על צוארי שונאיהם של ת"ח שיושבין ועוסקין בתורה בד בבד ולא עוד אלא שמטפשין כתיב הכא ונואלו וכתיב התם אשר נואלנו ולא עוד אלא שחוטאין שנאמר ואשר חטאנו ואיבעית אימא מהכא נואלו שרי צוען

The gemara learns that one should not learn alone and even,calls it a sin and one will become foolish. The Mahrsha says that one will truly understand Torah with study partners.

There may be a difference today because we have seforim which may act as study partners,but that is just my idea I never saw this written anywhere.

Comment: The mishna in avos says kinei licha chaver. One of the pshatim in the Bartenura is to buy sfarim.

Comment: there are exceptions such as rav elyashiv z'tl

Comment: Can you explain what  kinei licha chaver means ? Also what does the Bartenura and R Eliyashiv say exactly ?