# When, why and who originated Chevruta style studying?

Tags: history, torah-study, chavrusa

From reading various stories mentioned in the mishnah, it seems that students studied directly from their rav. I assume that they reviewed what they studied, and, perhaps, discussed ideas with each other.

But, there doesn't appear to be a mention to *chevruta* style learning which is common in yeshivot and Batei Midrash, today.

Who thought of this idea and why? What was the reasoning or motive? When did this idea begin?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45210/759

Comment: Also Eruvin Daf 50-something, in the list of things to aid in learning, and arguably the Mishnah of קנה לך חבר in Avos, depending on which Rishon’s understanding you go like.